How can I properly migrate from Google Signin to FedCM?
I am testing FedCM since third-party cookie is phasing out. However, I found that it could not be used properly after migration.
The first step in the migration guide says:

Add a boolean flag to enable FedCM when initializing using:
HTML, set the data-use_fedcm_for_prompt attribute to true.
JavaScript, set use_fedcm_for_prompt to true in the IdConfiguration object.

I modified them.my current code looks like this:
   <div id="g_id_onload"
     class="google-login"
     :data-client_id="constants.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
     :data-use_fedcm_for_prompt="true"
     :data-auto_select="true"
     :data-itp_support="true"
     :data-skip_prompt_cookie="localToken"
     :data-callback="handleGoogleOneTapResponse"
     :data-prompt_parent_id="g_id_onload"
     :data-ux_mode="'popup'">
   </div>

  function renderGoogleSignInBtn() {
    const google = window.google;
    if (google) {
      google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: constants.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        callback: handleGoogleOneTapResponse,
        use_fedcm_for_prompt: true,
      });
      google.accounts.id.prompt();
    }
  }

On Mac it works fine, but on Windows it reports an error!
Screenshot of the error
I don't quite understand why this is such a mistake.What do I need to do for a successful migration?

It looks like the error is due to your code calling google.accounts.id.prompt(); twice (one from HTML, and one from JavaScript). You shouldn't need to have both HTML and JavaScript in your code to use One Tap.
